# Google API Console - transfer project to another domain

Tags: api, google-api

I started a project, and used my personal email to get the api keys for my project.
Now, I got the domain for my app and set it up with google apps. My question is, is there an easy way to transfer the api keys from one account to another (they are both in different domains), or is it better just to suck it up and get new API keys?  The app is still under development, so I do not have to worry about users.

Comment: Seems like you already answered your question. However, I don't think it's possible to move project from one account to another. At least I could not find that possibility.